# Maxscale slow and lost connection

Tags: mariadb, maxscale

i have maxscale installed, I obtain this error:

```
Refresh rate limit exceeded for load of users' table.
```

what can I do? I have mariadb database

Answer (score 0):

When the authentication of a user fails, MaxScale reloads the list of database users. This reloading is rate limited which causes the error message in question to be logged.

Inspecting the error logs of MaxScale for any clues about the failed authentication attempts will allow you to fix of the root cause of the problem.

The MaxScale tutorial over at the MariaDB KB shows [How to set up MaxScale](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb-enterprise/mariadb-maxscale-21-setting-up-mariadb-maxscale/) and how to configure database grants for use with MaxScale.